# Twig Check for partial existence before include

Tags: symfony, twig

I am working on a fairly complex multi lingual site that will render different partials based on the html locale.

I have a partial structure that will use the locale appended to the file name to pick the right one. For example;

```
{% include '@BundleName/Layout/Text/_partial-name.' ~ htmlLocale ~ '.html.twig' with {'title' : resource.title } %}
```

Whilst this works, there is a risk if the locale selected has not (yet) had its partial created, this will throw an error. What i would like to do is check for the existence of the partial before trying to render it and fall back to a default if it does not yet exist.

```
{% if '@BundleName/Layout/Text/_partial-name.' ~ htmlLocale ~ '.html.twig' %} 
    {% include '@BundleName/Layout/Text/_partial-name.' ~ htmlLocale ~ '.html.twig' with {'title' : resource.title } %}
{% else %}
    {% include '@BundleName/Layout/Text/_partial-name.html.twig' with {'title' : resource.title } %} 
{% endif %}
```

Obviously that doesn't work, but that's the kind of thing i am after!

Answer (score 28, accepted):

Rather than to test if the partial exists you can use `ignore missing`:

```
{% include 'partial.html' ignore missing %}
```

If you do wish to have a fallback when the file is missing you can pass an array to the include function. This will make the include render the first found template in the array

```
{% include  [
                ('@BundleName/Layout/Text/_partial-name.' ~ htmlLocale ~ '.html.twig'), 
                '@BundleName/Layout/Text/_partial-name.html.twig'
            ] with {'title' : resource.title } %}
```

Comment: Perfect, this is exactly what i needed.

Comment: The ideal elegant solution! I've been started to write a custom extension to solve this issue, but happily, I've found this answer.

Comment: Did you create this answer with ChatGPT?

Answer (score 0):

You can use `|default` twig filter to determine a default value to a variable if the value is undefined or empty :

```
htmlLocale|default('en')
```

You can also check if the variable is empty and/or defined :

```
{% if htmlLocale is not empty and htmlLocale is defined %} 
    {% include '@BundleName/Layout/Text/_partial-name.' ~ htmlLocale ~ '.html.twig' with {'title' : resource.title } %}
{% else %}
    {% include '@BundleName/Layout/Text/_partial-name.html.twig' with {'title' : resource.title } %} 
{% endif %}
```

Comment: I think you may have missed the point of the question slightly; it's not to text if the locale is set, its to test if the partial exists. @DarkBee is pretty much spot on